# How can I get logLik or AIC of a vglm fit

Tags: r, vgam

I couldn't get them via normal methods.

```
> x <- rnorm(1000, 10, 1)
> y <-rgamma(1000, shape=1, rate=x)
> myfit <- vglm(y~x, family=gammaff(link="reciprocal"))
> summary(myfit)

Call:
vglm(formula = y ~ x, family = gammaff(link = "reciprocal"))

Pearson residuals:
         Min     1Q  Median      3Q     Max
1/mu -6.4126 -0.404 0.32118 0.69281 0.99917

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error  z value
(Intercept) 0.050464     2.9415 0.017156
x           0.987358     0.2974 3.320015

Number of linear predictors:  1 

Name of linear predictor: 1/mu 

(Estimated) Dispersion Parameter for gammaff family:   0.96865

Residual deviance: 1106.494 on 998 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations: 6 
> AIC(myfit)
numeric(0)

> showMethods("AIC")
Function: AIC (package stats)
object="ANY"
object="cao"
object="qrrvglm"
object="rrvglm"
object="vgam"
object="vglm"
object="vlm"
```

[Here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/vgam/docs/vglm) it referes to `AIC.vglm`, but that doesn't even exist.

The closest function I found is `AICrrvglm` or `AICvgam`, neither works.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that `logLik.vlm(myfit)` returns `NULL`. In the details of `?logLik.vlm`, it states that

> this code relies on the log-likelihood being defined, and computed,
>   for the object.

In your case the log-likelihood is not computed: It is documented in ?"vglmff-class" about the loglikelihood:

> loglikelihood: Object of class "function" returning the log-likelihood
>   of the model. This slot is optional. If present, the function must
>   have arguments function(mu, y, w, residuals = FALSE, eta, extra =
>   NULL). The argument residuals can be ignored because log-likelihood
>   residuals aren't defined.

Apparently `gammaff` does not contain this optional slot and therefore the loglikelihood was not computed and so the AIC cannot be computed either.

Comment: you might be able to hack up something with `logLik.vglm <- function(x) -x@criterion$deviance/2` , although there's something I'm not understanding at the moment about the way the methods are structured (S3/S4 confusion?)